# How to apply partitioned count for MultiResourceItemReader?

Tags: multithreading, spring-batch

I have a file of 50K records.  It takes close to 40 mins to insert it into a DB. So I thought of applying a partition to the step in such a way that the 50k records are partitioned between 10 threads (via `gridSize`) with each thread processing 1000 records in parallel.

All the forums show examples of using `JDBCPagingItemReader` and partitioned count set via execution context. 
Since I am using `MultiResourceItemReader`, how can I set the partition count(`startingIndex` and `endingIndex`  - refer code snippet below) for `MultiResourceItemReader`?

Please advise.

Code snippet of partitioner below:

```
public Map partition(int gridSize) {
    LOGGER.debug("START: Partition");
    Map partitionMap = new HashMap();
    int startingIndex = 0;
    int endingIndex =  1000;

    for(int i=0; i< gridSize; i++){
        ExecutionContext ctxMap = new ExecutionContext();
        ctxMap.putInt("startingIndex",startingIndex);
        ctxMap.putInt("endingIndex", endingIndex);

        startingIndex = endingIndex+1;
        endingIndex += 1000; 

        partitionMap.put("Thread:-"+i, ctxMap);
    }
    LOGGER.debug("END: Created Partitions of size: "+ partitionMap.size());
    return partitionMap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't set the partition count on the `MultiResourceItemReader`.  You use the `MultiResourcePartitioner` to create a partition per resource (file) and then have the reader pick up each file separately as it's own partition. With that configuration, you don't need the `MultiResourceItemReader` anymore as well (you can go straight to the delegate).

There is a sample of this use case in the Spring Batch samples and can be found here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/partitionFileJob.xml

Comment: Thanks for responding . I don't want partition per resource(File). I want the partition to happen for single file. Will this work for my scenario ?

Comment: Partitioning within a single file typically doesn't improve performance since the process is typically IO bound anyways.  What is the bottleneck here?  50k records shouldn't take that long to insert unless there is some other bottleneck...

Comment: I am trying to find the bottleneck. Is there any way that i can create multiple threads and configure each thread to process the specific count of records based on commit-interval?

Comment: Can you split the file?